# How do I only sum values in a excel column if names from two arrays correspond?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure the solution to the following is quite straightforward, but it has me stumped...

I want to perform the following in an excel workbook. Lets say in Column A we have an range of names, and in column B a range of values

```
A1 - Alan  B1 - 1
A2 - Bob   B2 - 0
A3 - Jim   B3 - 1
A4 - Tom   B4 - 2
```

I then receive a separate workbook with similar data that I need to add to the values in column B, but the new workbook does not contain all of the names in the original workbook, e.g.

```
A1 - Alan  B1 - 1
A2 - Jim   B2 - 2
A3 - Dave  B3 - 1
A4 - Tom   B4 - 1
```

I want to update the values of the original workbook in column B so that they give the sum of column B from each workbook, and append any new names from column A in the second (new) workbook to the range of names in column A in the original workbook.

Any newly appended names to column A should also display the related value from column B.

I'm currently using filters and updating values manually, the range of names is large, it's time consuming, it's driving me mad...I'm sure there is a more elegant solution to this.

Help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try PivotTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the easiest way to do it was to just put the new list on the same worksheet as the old list. This assumes you put the new list in column D (see `newCol`).

If you wanted to select a new workbook and grab from a specific sheet on it, we'd need to know how the new workbook would be selected (file selector, is it always in a certain file, can multiple files be selected, what would the sheet names be, etc.).

```
Sub AddAndAppend()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim origCol As Long, newCol As Long, startRow As Long

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'sets to the current worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'speeds up macro for longer lists
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'assumes a header row so starts on row 2
startRow = 2

'origcol is where the names are to start, newcol is where the names are in the new list
origCol = 1
newCol = 4

'loop through all the new names
For i = startRow To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, newCol).End(xlUp).Row
    'if name in new list is found in old list...
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range(ws.Cells(startRow, origCol), ws.Cells(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, origCol).End(xlUp).Row, origCol)), ws.Cells(i, newCol).Value) > 0 Then
        '...find the name in the old list and combine the values
        For j = startRow To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, origCol).End(xlUp).Row
            If ws.Cells(j, origCol).Value = ws.Cells(i, newCol).Value Then
                ws.Cells(j, origCol + 1).Value = ws.Cells(j, origCol + 1).Value + ws.Cells(i, newCol + 1).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Else
        '...otherwise, add the new name to the end of the old list
        ws.Cells(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, origCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1, origCol).Value = ws.Cells(i, newCol).Value
        ws.Cells(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, origCol).End(xlUp).Row, origCol + 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, newCol + 1).Value
    End If
Next i

'turns off speeding up
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description
Exit Sub

End Sub
```